# Format of arrays in Puppet

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to define an array in this format in my nodes.pp?

```
$servers = [
    {
        name => 'felix',
        ip   => '192.168.43.5',
        env  => 'prod',
    },
    {
        name => 'washington',
        ip   => '192.168.43.11',
        env  => 'uat',
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any reasons why that wouldn't work. Taken from the [puppet docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_datatypes.html#arrays):

```
$foo = [ 'one', {'second' => 'two', 'third' => 'three'} ]
notice( $foo[1]['third'] )
```

Not sure if the data has to be nested like that, due to some requirements, but wouldn't be more logical to organise the data like that ?

```
$servers = {
   felix      => { ip => '192.168.43.5',
                   env => 'prod', 
                 },
   washington => { ip => '192.168.43.11',
                   env => 'uat',
                 },
}
```

Comment: When I try it I keep getting puppet errors, so if I do this: `def::server::list { servers: $servers = [
    {
        name => 'felix',
        ip   => '192.168.43.5',
        env  => 'prod',
    },
    {
        name => 'washington',
        ip   => '192.168.43.11',
        env  => 'uat',
    },
]}` Why wouldn't that work? I keep getting the error: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at 'servers'; expected '}' Thanks Dan

Comment: The reason for that error is usually missing commas and/or colons. Double check the definition of your variable. Also I really don't understand why you were trying to do with that example.

Comment: Also send me the definition of the def::server::list class. It's possible that your defined type expect a different type for argument.